# What is the difference between != and is not? And Nulls in general

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding how t-sql treats null values.

As a C# guy, I tend to want to do

```
IF(@myVar != null)...
```

But, this doesn't ever appear to run my code. So I do

```
IF(@myVar is not null)
```

Whats the difference?

Second, the way addition works is unclear.  Let's say I have

```
declare @someCount int, @someFinalResult int

--Select that returns null
SELECT @someCount = columnName from tableName where someColumn = someValue
```

Then if I do

```
SET @someFinalResult = @someCount + 1--I seem to get NULL if I had null + something
```

But, if I first

```
declare @someCount int, @someFinalResult int
--FIRST SET DEFAULT TO 0
SET @someCount = 0

--Select that returns null
SELECT @someCount = columnName from tableName where someColumn = someValue
```

Now, `@someCount` defaults to 0, it's not actually set equal to NULL even if the result is null.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deal with [NULL in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504.aspx) you basically work with [3-value logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) with all the [implications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131081.aspx).

So in your example

`IF(@myVar != null)` vs `IF(@myVar is not null)`

It basically boils down to the question what is the difference between: `@myVar = null` vs `@myVar is null`

`@myVar = null` will always evaluate to null as what you are asking is:

> is the value in @myVar **equal to** UNKNOWN

As you do not know what the UNKNOWN is this question cannot by answered yes, or no so it evaluates to **UNKNOWN**

```
e.g. 
    "is 1 = UNKNOWN" - I do not know
    "is 'a' = UNKNOWN" - I do not know 
    "is UNKNOWN = UNKNOWN" - I do not know
```

The last one may be a bit tricky but just imagine that you have 2 boxes with apples and you do not know neither how many apples are in box1 one nor in box2 so asking:

```
is count(box1) = count(box2)
is the same as 
is UNKNOWN = UNKNOWN"
```

so the answer is `I do not know`

the second one `@myVar is null` is different as it is like asking

```
is the value in @myVar UNKNOWN
```

so the difference is that you specifically ask "is it true that the value stored in the variable is UNKNOWN?", so

```
    "is 1 UNKNOWN" - NO
    "is 'a' UNKNOWN" - NO
    "is UNKNOWN UNKNOWN" - YES
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's like this: `NULL` is unknown, so `!=NULL` is also unknown, because you don't know if it's equal or not. And you know even less whether two unknowns are equal. The same goes for more or less any operation with unknowns, when you add something to unknown the result is hardly any more known to you.